# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-performance

I started to get the following crashed on Fabric:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)


Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.zzar(Unknown Source:10)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.zzbf(Unknown Source:22)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzat.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzat.zza(Unknown Source:1)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfUrlConnection.instrument(Unknown Source:9)
       at io.branch.referral.network.BranchRemoteInterfaceUrlConnection.doRestfulPost(BranchRemoteInterfaceUrlConnection.java:127)
       at io.branch.referral.network.BranchRemoteInterfaceUrlConnection.doRestfulPost(BranchRemoteInterfaceUrlConnection.java:45)
       at io.branch.referral.network.BranchRemoteInterface.make_restful_post(BranchRemoteInterface.java:136)
       at io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchPostTask.doInBackground(Branch.java:2860)
       at io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchPostTask.doInBackground(Branch.java:2835)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

With the following configuration:

on the root build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
```

and in the app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

...

api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.2"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6"

...

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Does someone know a working configuration, or a way to fix it? 
The crash rate for this is high.

[image: Devices distribution for the crash]

Comment: I am stuck in this same bug, I have removed the firebase performance metrics for now, will wait for firebase teams fix.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this is an known issue by Google and they are working on fix it:

Please check this link for more detail: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/7Ccu-Zh8pdg

My workaround was to downgrade library versions, below the configuration that work for me:

```
'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
"com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
"com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.0.0"
"com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
```

I hope that help!

Comment: I am stuck in this same bug, I have removed the firebase performance metrics for now, will wait for firebase teams fix.